# Why am I getting this parse error?

Tags: php, html, forms, parse-error

I am getting the following error when I run my php script:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\get-started.php on line 43.
```

This is line 43:

```
!isset($_POST['budget']) || empty($_POST['budget'])
```

Code:

```
if(
    !isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['company']) || empty($_POST['company'])
    !isset($_POST['budget']) || empty($_POST['budget'])
    !isset($_POST['message']) || empty($_POST['message'])
){
}else{
    $body = "From: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n E-Mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n Company: " . $_POST['company'] . "\n Monthly Budget: " . $_POST['budget'] . "\n Message: " . $_POST['message'] "";
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p class="success">Awesome, your message was sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p class="error">Uh oh, something went wrong, try again.</p>'; 
    }
}
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to reconsider the way you're doing this (see edit) but in the mean time, I suspect the following is the problem:

```
!isset($_POST['company']) || empty($_POST['company'])
!isset($_POST['budget']) || empty($_POST['budget'])
```

Add `||` after.

```
!isset($_POST['company']) || empty($_POST['company']) ||
!isset($_POST['budget']) || empty($_POST['budget']) ||
```

Your other error is coming from:

```
 $body = "From: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n E-Mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n Company: " . $_POST['company'] . "\n Monthly Budget: " . $_POST['budget'] . "\n Message: " . $_POST['message'] "" //<-- These are no good.
```

Those quotes at the end are not good, get rid of them.

```
$body = "From: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n E-Mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n Company: " . $_POST['company'] . "\n Monthly Budget: " . $_POST['budget'] . "\n Message: " . $_POST['message'];
```

**Edit**:
In many cases (note I said many, not most, not all), `isset()` and `empty()` do not need to be used in conjunction. `isset()` checks if the value is set to *anything*, including 0 and ''. `empty()` will check if it is set and if it is, will see if it is what most people would consider an "empty" value, such as null, '', 0, and others.

So, I tend to just use `!empty()` or `isset()` which are sufficient on their own.

Comment: It solved that issue but now I am getting;; T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: @user3232801 check my updated answer, should solve that error.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Thanks! I saw you said to reconsider the way I am doing this, would you mind showing me the correct way?

Comment: Foooor sure, check my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

You're missing `||` at the end of line 42, and 43.

It should be:

```
if(
    !isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['company']) || empty($_POST['company']) ||  // <-- here
    !isset($_POST['budget']) || empty($_POST['budget']) ||    // <-- here
    !isset($_POST['message']) || empty($_POST['message'])
)
```

Protip: When the compiler/parser points out a line number, don't assume that the problem is guaranteed to be on that line. It may be on the line before (like in this case), or it may be dozens of lines before. Or it may be on a line after.  The key is this: the compiler/parser didn't like or expect what it saw at the given line. Why not?

---

At the end of this line:

```
$body = "From: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n E-Mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n Company: " . $_POST['company'] . "\n Monthly Budget: " . $_POST['budget'] . "\n Message: " . $_POST['message'] "";
```

you have

```
$_POST['message'] "";
```

Remove those `""`, or add a concatenation operator (`.`) to concatenate a (pointless) empty string.

Comment: I added the || but I am now getting a T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error. I will remember that tip, thank you.

Comment: Answer has been edited.

Comment: I removed the "" and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some logical or (`||`) at the end of line 42, and line 43.

Resolve it to:

`if(
    !isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['company']) || empty($_POST['company']) ||   //<----
    !isset($_POST['budget']) || empty($_POST['budget']) ||     //<----
    !isset($_POST['message']) || empty($_POST['message'])
    ){`

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using to check for empty and isset is very inneffecitent. Looking at the PHP documentation for the [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/empty) function, you can see the following.

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE

```
if(
   empty($_POST['name'])    ||
   empty($_POST['email'])   ||
   empty($_POST['company']) ||
   empty($_POST['budget'])  ||
   empty($_POST['message'])) 
{
   // Something is empty.
}
```

And if you do ever need to use `isset()` in the future, you can comma seperate all of the variables in one function call to check all of the variables. It will then return false if any one of the following parameters are not set, this doesn't work with `empty()` though.

```
if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['company'])) }
   // name, email and company are all set
}
```

Comment: So you are saying I should remove !isset($_POST['name']) ||, ect from the if (    ) for my code to be efficient? If not do you think you could put what you mean in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Well, I doubt it has any real different in performance, but since you are already using `empty()` there is no point to use `isset()` for the same variables.